# What is the font and/or size of the text in the mentioned webpage?

Tags: website-design, font

Here is the webpage I am referring to: http://yplanapp.com

If you see the text behind a green background immediately under the homepage, I was curious about the font and size of the text. The CSS content is not visible, hence if someone could recognize it's font and size, it would be of great help for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is not an UX question. StackOverflow would be more appropriate for this.

Comment: I flagged as "site review" but your assessment is more accurate. OP, please read the [help] and [about] pages to learn more about using UX.SE!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identifying a font family.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS is well visible in Chrome's developer tools:

[image: A screengrab of Chrome developer tools on the site in question]